# Which would be better refinerycms with heroku vs Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, heroku, refinerycms

I'm setting up a mainly informational site to promote epilepsy research and trying to do it as cheaply as possible. I have a lot of experience with Rails, but I was thinking maybe Wordpress might be a better way to go using a free blog on wordpress.com. However, as soon as I began trying to customize it a bit there was going to be a $30 charge. At that point I kind of wonder if I'd be better just throwing up a refinerycms based site which I could customize as much as I want on Heroku or even get a tiny instance on AWS. I think refinery uses imagemagick for image processing. Does that cost and which out of these 3 options: wordpress.com, refinerycms on heroku, refinerycms on aws would be recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the three options you mention, I have only used RefineryCMS on Heroku (for 3 different websites)

As you have lots of Rails experience, I can recommend Refinery. If you didn't know rails I wouldn't say that as there is a wee bit of a learning curve getting up to speed with Refinery. For straight vanilla CMS stuff, then Refinery is very easy to get going with, but you can also customise it yourself without huge hassles (or by spending cash up front) later on. There is plenty of other info on the internet re. heroku vs aws. I think the general consensus is that Heroku is easier to get started with, but (as always) it depends! I know someone serving 250,000 page hits a month from a free Heroku account with rails.

I expect this question will be shut-down as it is more of an opinion-based question rather than give me the facts... Anyway, hope this is somewhat helpful to you.

Comment: Definitely helpful, so marked it correct. After messing round with WP for a bit I decided to just go for it with refinery on heroku and haven't looked back. I'm sure WP is great, but right now I want to be able to set things up how I want them and refinery is so far extremely easy to use.